# Parallel line through Incenter of △ABC

Tags: geometry

Let ***I*** be incenter of **△ABC**. Let l be line through ***I*** parallel to **AB**, that intersects the sides **CA** and **CB** at **M** and **N**, respectively. Prove that ***AM + BN = MN***.

My work:

**Given: MN || AB**

**Claim :** MI = AM and BN = NI

**Proof:**
Let **angle MAI = angle IAB** = a, and **angle NBI = angle IBA** = b, **angle MCI = angle NCI** = y.

∴ By angle sum property in △ABC, we have,

2(a+b+y)=180 => a+b = 90 - y, By putting this value in **△AIB**, we have

**angle IAB** + **angle IBA** = **angle AIB** = 90-y,

not getting how I can step further ?? any hints

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please consider using MathJax to typeset mathematical expressions in your posts. Additionally, use `$\|$` to get $\|$. Also `$\angle$` gives $\angle$ , and `$\triangle$` gives $\triangle$ .

Comment: You seem close (to me), and just have to remember what is is that you're angle chasing for. Assuming that your claim is true, you'd want to show that $IAM$ is an isosceles triangle. You've got one angle $ \angle MAI = a$, and just need to hunt down the other $\angle MIA$. Can you show that it is equal to $a$?

Comment: Note that $\angle IAB + \angle IBA = \angle AIB $ doesn't seem right to me. These are 3 angles in triangle $IAB$, so should sum up to $180^\circ$. So can you elaborate on this part, esp if you want to use it further? (I agree that the LHS is $a+b$, but not the RHS)

Answer (score 1):

Since $I$ is the incenter, $\angle NBI=\angle IBA$.

And since by parallelism $$\angle CNI=\angle CBA=2\angle NBI$$ and also$$\angle CNI=\angle NBI+\angle BIN$$ then$$2\angle NBI=\angle NBI+\angle BIN$$and$$\angle NBI=\angle BIN$$[image: AM+BN=MN]
Therefore $\triangle IBN$ is isosceles and$$IN=NB$$In the same way you can show that $\triangle AIM$ is isosceles, and hence$$AM+BN=MN$$

Comment: @Calvin Lin: I meant "can show" in last sentence.  Is not $\triangle AIM$ proven isosceles by the same argument that shows $\triangle BIN$ is isosceles?

Comment: Oh sorry, I was mixing up AIM and AIB (from OP's last line). You're right that $AIM$ is isosceles.